# Faster JavaScript fuzzy string matching function?

Tags: javascript, strings, regex

I'm using the following function to fuzzy match strings:

```
function fuzzy_match(str,pattern){
    pattern = pattern.split("").reduce(function(a,b){ return a+".*"+b; });
    return (new RegExp(pattern)).test(str);
};
```

Example:

```
fuzzy_match("fogo","foo") //true
fuzzy_match("jquery.js","jqjs") //true
fuzzy_match("jquery.js","jr") //false
```

It's very slow, though. How can I optimize that function?

Comment: Why is [360k operations per second](http://jsperf.com/fuzzy-match) slow? If your application is slow, I think the problem is not there.

Comment: The third example returns `true` as well. `jquery.js` does match `j.*r`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
function fuzzy_match(str,pattern){
    pattern = pattern.split("").reduce(function(a,b){ return a+".*"+b; });
    return (new RegExp(pattern)).test(str);
};
```

1. String concatenation is slow. The reason is that you need to allocate new memory anytime you concatenate two strings. A smart compiler may optimise that,  but not too much. However, what you are trying to do with that `reduce` already exists, and it's called `join`:

   ```
    pattern = pattern.split("").join(".*")
   ```
2. The regex itself can be optimised: `.*` initially grabs as much as possible, then retracts only if the rest doesn't match. This takes a larger than neccessary amount of backtracking to find out. Instead, you could use a reluctant quantifier: `.*?`. This attempts to match as little as possible. If a match is found, it is found without backtracking. However, it still does a lot of backtracking if there is no match. We can do better: `a[^b]*b` (at this point, it doesn't really matter if the quantifier is greedy). A possessive quantifier (`a[^b]*+b`) would be even better, but [javascript doesn't support these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2824334/499214). Using a character class deprives us of a join, but see the next point.

   ```
    pattern = pattern.split("").reduce(function(a,b){ return a+'[^'+b+']*'+b; });
   ```
3. Since you are complaining about an operation that [takes about 3000 ns](http://jsperf.com/fuzzy-match) (as noted in the comments), it can be assumed you are doing a *lot* of queries. If there are very few patterns, you can cache your regexes. [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) has a handy function that I'll demonstrate, but you could easily build the cache yourself.

   ```
    var cache = _.memoize(function(pattern){
      return new RegExp(pattern.split("").reduce(function(a,b){
        return a+'[^'+b+']*'+b;
      })
    })
    function fuzzy_match(str,pattern){
      return cache(pattern).test(str)
    };
   ```
4. If there is a lot of repetition among the tested strings, you should use these as a pattern instead, and the pattern as the tested string. This is even easier. I will also demonstrate how to scope your variables using the export pattern. Also, a bugfix must be inserted here (we can't assume all characters in the string are alphanumeric), to properly escape non-alphanumeric characters:

   ```
    var fuzzy_match = (function(){
      var cache = _.memoize(function(str){
        return new RegExp("^"+str.replace(/./g, function(x){
          return /[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/.test(x) ? "\\"+x+"?" : x+"?";
        })+"$");
      });
      return function(str, pattern){
        return cache(str).test(pattern)
      });
    })();
   ```

---

Concerning the last regex:

Given some pattern `"ace"`, the regex you build (`/a.*c.*e/`) tests if the string contains the characters of the pattern in the string, in the correct order.

If you want to test if a given string "abcde" is matched some pattern: The pattern must only contain the characters of the string, in the correct order: `/^a?b?c?d?e?$/`. To do this, we regex-escape every regex special character (pattern source: [CoolAj86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)), make every character optional (`?`), and flank the regex with string boundary anchors.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you very much. If not abuse might I ask you to elaborate only a little bit on that last regexp?

Comment: @Dokkat explanation added. Proper escaping added.

Answer (score 0):

My solution might be not fast enough for you (200k ops/s) :) but beside true/false it also provides informations about the match:

In some cases, you might need to know it eg. to make parts of your input bold in the search results

It's written in typescript (if you want to use it - I've published it here - https://github.com/pie6k/fuzzystring) and demo here https://pie6k.github.io/fuzzystring/

It works like:

```
fuzzyString('liolor', 'lorem ipsum dolor sit');

// returns
{
  parts: [
    { content: 'l', type: 'input' },
    { content: 'orem ', type: 'fuzzy' },
    { content: 'i', type: 'input' },
    { content: 'psum d', type: 'fuzzy' },
    { content: 'olor', type: 'input' },
    { content: ' sit', type: 'suggestion' },
  ],
  score: 0.87,
}
```

Here is full implementation (Typescript)

```
type MatchRoleType = 'input' | 'fuzzy' | 'suggestion';

interface FuzzyMatchPart {
  content: string;
  type: MatchRoleType;
}

interface FuzzyMatchData {
  parts: FuzzyMatchPart[];
  score: number;
}

interface FuzzyMatchOptions {
  truncateTooLongInput?: boolean;
  isCaseSesitive?: boolean;
}

function calculateFuzzyMatchPartsScore(fuzzyMatchParts: FuzzyMatchPart[]) {
  const getRoleLength = (role: MatchRoleType) =>
    fuzzyMatchParts
      .filter((part) => part.type === role)
      .map((part) => part.content)
      .join('').length;

  const fullLength = fuzzyMatchParts.map((part) => part.content).join('')
    .length;
  const fuzzyLength = getRoleLength('fuzzy');
  const inputLength = getRoleLength('input');
  const suggestionLength = getRoleLength('suggestion');

  return (
    (inputLength + fuzzyLength * 0.7 + suggestionLength * 0.9) / fullLength
  );
}

function compareLetters(a: string, b: string, isCaseSensitive = false) {
  if (isCaseSensitive) {
    return a === b;
  }
  return a.toLowerCase() === b.toLowerCase();
}

function fuzzyString(
  input: string,
  stringToBeFound: string,
  { truncateTooLongInput, isCaseSesitive }: FuzzyMatchOptions = {},
): FuzzyMatchData | false {
  // make some validation first

  // if input is longer than string to find, and we dont truncate it - it's incorrect
  if (input.length > stringToBeFound.length && !truncateTooLongInput) {
    return false;
  }

  // if truncate is enabled - do it
  if (input.length > stringToBeFound.length && truncateTooLongInput) {
    input = input.substr(0, stringToBeFound.length);
  }

  // if input is the same as string to be found - we dont need to look for fuzzy match - return it as match
  if (input === stringToBeFound) {
    return {
      parts: [{ content: input, type: 'input' }],
      score: 1,
    };
  }

  const matchParts: FuzzyMatchPart[] = [];

  const remainingInputLetters = input.split('');

  // let's create letters buffers
  // it's because we'll perform matching letter by letter, but if we have few letters matching or not matching in the row
  // we want to add them together as part of match
  let ommitedLettersBuffer: string[] = [];
  let matchedLettersBuffer: string[] = [];

  // helper functions to clear the buffers and add them to match
  function addOmmitedLettersAsFuzzy() {
    if (ommitedLettersBuffer.length > 0) {
      matchParts.push({
        content: ommitedLettersBuffer.join(''),
        type: 'fuzzy',
      });
      ommitedLettersBuffer = [];
    }
  }

  function addMatchedLettersAsInput() {
    if (matchedLettersBuffer.length > 0) {
      matchParts.push({
        content: matchedLettersBuffer.join(''),
        type: 'input',
      });
      matchedLettersBuffer = [];
    }
  }

  for (let anotherStringToBeFoundLetter of stringToBeFound) {
    const inputLetterToMatch = remainingInputLetters[0];

    // no more input - finish fuzzy matching
    if (!inputLetterToMatch) {
      break;
    }

    const isMatching = compareLetters(
      anotherStringToBeFoundLetter,
      inputLetterToMatch,
      isCaseSesitive,
    );

    // if input letter doesnt match - we'll go to the next letter to try again
    if (!isMatching) {
      // add this letter to buffer of ommited letters
      ommitedLettersBuffer.push(anotherStringToBeFoundLetter);
      // in case we had something in matched letters buffer - clear it as matching letters run ended
      addMatchedLettersAsInput();
      // go to the next input letter
      continue;
    }

    // we have input letter matching!

    // remove it from remaining input letters
    remainingInputLetters.shift();

    // add it to matched letters buffer
    matchedLettersBuffer.push(anotherStringToBeFoundLetter);
    // in case we had something in ommited letters buffer - add it to the match now
    addOmmitedLettersAsFuzzy();

    // if there is no more letters in input - add this matched letter to match too
    if (!remainingInputLetters.length) {
      addMatchedLettersAsInput();
    }
  }

  // if we still have letters left in input - means not all input was included in string to find - input was incorrect
  if (remainingInputLetters.length > 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // lets get entire matched part (from start to last letter of input)
  const matchedPart = matchParts.map((match) => match.content).join('');

  // get remaining part of string to be found
  const suggestionPart = stringToBeFound.replace(matchedPart, '');

  // if we have remaining part - add it as suggestion
  if (suggestionPart) {
    matchParts.push({ content: suggestionPart, type: 'suggestion' });
  }
  const score = calculateFuzzyMatchPartsScore(matchParts);

  return {
    score,
    parts: matchParts,
  };
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].