# Is this code for getting the dependency tree of a file correct?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, functional-programming, graph

```
function dep_tree(graph,node,prev_deps){
    return uniq(flatten(graph[node].map(function(child_node){ 
        if (contains(prev_deps,child_node))
            throw "Circular reference between "+child_node+" and "+node;
        return dep_tree(graph,child_node,prev_deps ? prev_deps.concat(node) : [node]) 
    })).concat(node));
};
```

- `graph` is an object such as `{a:[],b:["a"],c:[],d:["b","c"]}`, that links a file, ex: `"d"` to it's dependencies `"b" "c"`.
- `file` is the the node to search.
- `prev_deps` is internal, to keep track of visited nodes

The function returns the full dependency tree of that node. For example, `dep_tree(that_obj_above,"d") = ["b","c","a"]`. Is this code correct, overall? Is it correctly checking for circular dependencies? Is there a name for what I'm doing?

Comment: `uniq`, `flatten` are imported from `underscore.js`?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, I forgot to mention, sorry. Do I know you? That name sounds familiar.

Comment: [We have met before](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23905/22489)

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh sure you're the guy who made my fuzzy_match faster than assembly, thanks for that! Actually that was your only answer...!? Why!?

Comment: I don't come often to CR. I know I should.

Comment: Also see my own solution to that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303040/javascript-dependency-list/13303185#13303185

Answer (score 2):

Not a lot of code to review,

- To reduce confusion, I would use `_.uniq()` rather than point straight to `uniq()`
- lowerCamelCase is preferred, `child_node` -> `childNode`
- `dep_tree` is unfortunate, I like `recursiveDependencies` better
- I would have set `prev_deps = prev_deps || [];` prior to return, it would make your recursive call less golfic:

  ```
  return dep_tree(graph,child_node, prev_deps.concat(node) )
  ```